# How to get place name using longitude and latitude in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have only lon and lat.
I need the address and phone no of the object at the given lon and lat.
How would I do it using only JavaScript?

I additionally need to show a marker (infowindow.set(address and phone no)).

this is my code:

```
var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
      position: new google.maps.LatLng(aCars[0],aCars[1]),
      map: map,
      title: 'My workplace',
      clickable: false,
      icon: 'images/images.png'
      });   
      google.maps.event.addListener(marker,'mouseover',function() {
          infowindow.setContent(     );
      infowindow.open(map, this);
      });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out the reverse geocoding API by google, although i double you'll actually get a phone number, you'll have to talk to a phonebook api for that i'm afraid.

http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/geocoding/#ReverseGeocoding

Comment: how get place name in my code.i have lat and lan.any shortget are there using lan and lat.

Comment: Check the Google Maps JS API v3 docs, this is a direct link to a javascript example of the reverse geocoding api: http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/javascript/services.html#ReverseGeocoding

Comment: very very thank you.it is working very nice. but how to get with phone no.

Comment: Like i said, the google geocoding API doesn't contain any phonenumbers, you'll need to find another api to do that.

Answer (score 1):

1. You Can Use Geodatasource API to get a Place or area name! 500 req/month Free

   ```
     fetch('https://api.geodatasource.com/city? 
    key=YOUR_KEY&&format=json&lat=22.3072&lng=73.1812')
   .then((response) => response.json())
   .then((responseJson) => {

     Alert.alert(responseJson.city+","+responseJson.region)
     console.log(responseJson.city);
   })
   .catch((error) => {
     console.error(error);
   });
   ```